# Line break in self-defined function and enlignment-environment

Tags: math-mode, align, environments

I´m struggling with the following problem: I have an align-environment with 5 rows and I´d like to have a line break in one of the rows, because of the length of the line. The problem is that I have a self-defined function `\E` with a `\left[` and `\right]` statement around the whole argument, which prevents the line break in between.

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\var{Var(}{)} 
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\mathbb{E}\left[{#1}\right]} %expectation
\newcommand{\bet}[3]{\beta^{{#1}}_{{#2}}({#3})}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
        %Line 1
        \var{\bet{}{k}{\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{X}_n,r_n)}}& \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \E{[\bet{}{k} 
        {\mathcal{X}_n,r_n} - \bet{}{k}{\mathcal{X}_{n+1} \setminus \{X_i\},r_n}]^2}\\
        %Line 2
        & = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \E{[\bet{}{k}{\mathcal{X}_n,r_n}-\bet{}{k}{\mathcal{X}_n 
        \setminus \{X_i\},r_n}  \\ 
        %Line 3
        & \phantom{{}=} + \bet{}{k}{\mathcal{X}_n \setminus \{X_i\},r_n} - \bet{}{k} 
        {\mathcal{X}_{n+1}\setminus \{X_i\},r_n}^2]} \\
        %Line 4
        & \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 4 \sqrt{\Delta_k} \\
        %Line 5
        & = 2n \sqrt{\Delta_k}.
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

It isn´t working, because my function `\E` goes from line 2 to line 3.
How do i make it work? Thanks in advance!

PS: I also don´t think the `\phantom{{}=}` is an elegant solution to reach correct intendation. Is there a correct way to do it?

Comment: You cannot break a `\left....\right` construction across lines, why do you think I told you using `\left....\right` by default was a bad idea?

Comment: For your PS, align in the right on the `=`'s but use `= {} &` not just `=&` (else wrong spacing), then no need for a phantom

Comment: Also please complete your MWE: where is the definition of `\var`?

Comment: This is just one of those instances where you cannot use a macro for the entire expactation macro.

Comment: I know, but i wanted to show my intention what I would like to have. Do you know an good working alternative? (I also completed my MWE)

Comment: In this case typeset it by hand. BTW your `\var` is not good `var` will not be upright. And `{var(}` is not a delimiter so `\var*` will not work. Look up `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` in the `mathtools` manual, for the prefix you can use `\operatorname{var}`

Comment: There will be situations where using macros are inpractical. So I always make sure the symbol, here for example `\mathbb{E}` is available in a separate macro name, then I can use it manually if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I'd adjust it

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}


\DeclareMathOperator\var{var}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Var[1]{\var}{(}{)}{}{#1} 

\newcommand\ExpecSymbol{\mathbb{E}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\E[1]{\ExpecSymbol}{[}{]}{}{#1}

\newcommand{\bet}[3]{\beta^{{#1}}_{{#2}}({#3})}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  % Line 1
  \Var[\big]{\bet{}{k}{\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{X}_n,r_n)}} \leq{}& \frac{1}{2}
  \sum_{i=1}^n \E[\big]{[\bet{}{k} {\mathcal{X}_n,r_n} -
    \bet{}{k}{\mathcal{X}_{n+1} \setminus \{X_i\},r_n}]^2}
  \\
  % Line 2
  = {} & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n
  \ExpecSymbol\Bigl[\bet{}{k}{\mathcal{X}_n,r_n}-\bet{}{k}{\mathcal{X}_n
    \setminus \{X_i\},r_n}
  \\
  % Line 3
  &  + \bet{}{k}{\mathcal{X}_n \setminus \{X_i\},r_n} -
  \bet{}{k} {\mathcal{X}_{n+1}\setminus \{X_i\},r_n}^2\Bigr]
  \\
  % Line 4
  \leq {} & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 4 \sqrt{\Delta_k}
  \\
  % Line 5
  = {} & 2n \sqrt{\Delta_k}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats perfect! Thank you again.